# how to concat group using pivot mysql

Tags: mysql, pivot, concatenation

"concat group", for pivot rows to columns.

my sql:

```
 select month(device_datetime) as month,
           device_platform as platform,
           count(*) as total
    from devices
    group by month(device_datetime), platform
    order by month desc
```

the result is what I want, but I want to make the platform columns

```
month  | platform | total
   02  | windows  | 10
   02  | android  | 08
   03  | windows  | 06
   04  | Macintosh| 04
```

I want like this:

```
   month  | windows  | android | macintosh
      02  | 10       | 08      | 0
      03  | 06       | 0       | 0
      04  | 0        | 0       | 04
```

Thank you. I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this (case and if method)

```
CASE METHOD
        SELECT month(device_datetime) AS month,
        SUM(CASE WHEN device_platform = 'windows' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS windows,
        SUM(CASE WHEN device_platform = 'android' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS android,
        SUM(CASE WHEN device_platform = 'Macintosh' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Macintosh
        FROM devices
        GROUP BY month(device_datetime)
        ORDER BY month desc


  IF METHOD
        SELECT month(device_datetime) as month,
        SUM(IF(device_platform= 'windows', 1, 0) ) as windows  ,
        SUM(IF(device_platform= 'android', 1, 0) ) as android, 
        SUM(IF(device_platform= 'Macintosh', 1, 0) ) as macintosh           
        FROM devices
        GROUP BY month(device_datetime)
        ORDER BY month desc
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional sum with IF operator. Check the following query

```
       select month(device_datetime) as month,
       SUM(IF(device_platform= 'windows', 1, 0) ) as windows  ,
       SUM(IF(device_platform= 'android', 1, 0) ) as android, 
       SUM(IF(device_platform= 'Macintosh', 1, 0) ) as macintosh           
       from devices
       group by month(device_datetime)
       order by month desc
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
  select month,
       IF(device_platform= 'windows', total, 0) as windows  ,
       IF(device_platform= 'android', total, 0) as android, 
       IF(device_platform= 'Macintosh', total, 0) as macintosh           
       from devices
       group by month
       order by month
```